# Нужны ли запятые в данных примерах?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Ты не знаешь даже как пройти в библиотеку ?/!
2. Ты даже не знаешь где находится "нофелет" ?/!
3. Он не знает даже куда обратиться ?/!

Answer (score 4):

Ты не знаешь даже, как пройти в библиотеку ?/!

Ты даже не знаешь, где находится "нофелет" ?/!

Он не знает даже,  куда обратиться ?/!

Пояснение

1) **Частица относится к глаголу в главном предложении, может менять свою позицию и не оказывает влияния на постанову запятой в СПП между главной и изъяснительной частью.**

2) А в чем тогда дело? А дело в том, что есть такое правило:

Запятая между главным и придаточным предложением ставится при наличии усилительных и выделительных частиц, а также пояснительных и присоединительных союзов перед подчинительным союзом,например:  Он не пользовался страховкой, даже когда это было совершенно необходимо.

3) Может быть, и нам можно написать: "Ты не знаешь,  даже как пройти в библиотеку"?

Но в СПП со значением изъяснения частицу ДАЖЕ нельзя отнести к придаточному, так как союз/союзное слово делит предложение на две обособленные части, никак не связанные друг с другом.

Answer (score 2):

Ты не знаешь даже, как пройти в библиотеку ?/!

Ты даже не знаешь, где находится "нофелет" ?/!

Он не знает даже, куда обратиться ?/!